Fine tuning BERT model for text generation (crossword solver)
I need assistance in my NLP project, where the goal is to predict a list of possible answers for a given crossword clue. The idea is to fine tune a BERT model using a dataset of crossword clue - answer pairs.
train.source looks like this :
Line at an airport, Kind of omelet, Susa was its capital, Suffix with cavern ... or gorge?, Nine: Prefix, Dragon's prey, Some pyrotechnics, ...
train.targets looks like this : LIMOS, EGGWHITE, ELAM, OUS, ENNEA, MAIDEN, FLARES, ...
For now, what I have is a loading function for the dataset in train, test and val. (len(train) = 433034, len(val) = 72304, len(test) = 72940)
I've loaded two models from BERT, the tokeniser and the model :
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

Then I've create a BERTDataset class :
class BERTDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, tokenizer, texts, targets=None, max_length=512):
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.texts = texts
        self.targets = targets  # Optionally used if specific target responses are provided
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.texts)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text = self.texts[idx]
        # Append '[MASK]' to the end of the text
        text_with_mask = text + " ? [MASK]."
        
        # Encoding the text with the appended MASK token
        encoding = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
            text_with_mask,
            max_length=self.max_length,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )
        
        input_ids = encoding['input_ids'].squeeze(0)  # Remove batch dimension
        attention_mask = encoding['attention_mask'].squeeze(0)

        # Labels should ideally be -100 where no prediction is needed
        labels = input_ids.detach().clone()
        # Set labels to -100 where the input IDs are not masked
        labels[labels != self.tokenizer.mask_token_id] = -100

        return {
            'input_ids': input_ids,
            'attention_mask': attention_mask,
            'labels': labels
        }

train_dataset = BERTDataset(tokenizer, train_sources, train_targets, max_length=128)
val_dataset = BERTDataset(tokenizer, val_sources, val_targets, max_length=128)

And finally launched the training :
from transformers import TrainingArguments,Trainer

# Define training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          # output directory
    num_train_epochs=3,              # number of training epochs
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,   # batch size for training
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,   # batch size for evaluation
    warmup_steps=500,                # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
    weight_decay=0.005,               # strength of weight decay
    logging_dir='./logs',            # directory for storing logs
    logging_steps=10,
)

# Initialize the Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    
    #compute_metrics=lambda eval_pred: {"loss" : eval_pred.loss}
)

# Start training
trainer.train()

I've encountered some problem, and the main one is that the training loss goes to 0 very quickly and I don't understand why (starting from step 510, the training loss is 0):

Is there anything I did wrong ? I really don't get why the model is not training correctly. Thank you !!

Is the evaluation bad? Is no, thats nice. If your evaluation is bad you might have some bug somewhere. It definitely strange that it is so low, can you show an input & output pair.
